# Check Picklist Value versus PriorValue

Tags: administration, workflow, formula, developer-productivity

Anyone have any clue how I can check along these lines (but actually have it work)?

```
not( ispickval( priorvalue( WebDev_Category__c ) , WebDev_Category__c ) )
```

I simply want part of a Workflow formula to determine if the category field has changed.  (sigh)  I'm lost for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `IsChanged(WebDev_Category__c)` in your formula your workflow, but be aware that this function is only available in workflows set to:

> Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s
>   edited.

For more information, see the [function's documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US#ISCHANGED).

Comment: I later realized that using that option on the Workflow itself resolved my issue.  Thanks!  ;)

Comment: are you sure it is working? but i found ischanged is not support picklist field.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it supports picklists. Are you sure you have the correct run option for your workflow?